# TCPDF alignment rendering issue

Tags: tcpdf

I'm getting weird alignment issues with TCPDF.

Here's a chunk of my looping code:

```
$pdf->setColor('text', 255, 255, 255);
$pdf->SetFontSize(20);
$pdf->Cell( 180, 25, $post->post_title, 0, 1, 'R', false, '', 3);

$pdf->Ln(1);

$pdf->setColor('text', 0, 0, 0);
$pdf->SetFontSize(14);
$pdf->Cell( 180, 8, $product->get_sku(), 0, 1, 'R', false);

$pdf->Ln(4);

$pdf->Image( $product->post->thumbnail, 15, 50, 80, 0, 'JPG', '', '', true, 150, '', false, false, 0, false, false, false);

$pdf->SetFontSize(10);
$pdf->MultiCell(90, 0, '', 1, 'C', 1, 0, '', '', true, 0, false, true, 0, 'T');
$pdf->setCellHeightRatio(1.65);
$pdf->MultiCell(90, 0, ($post->post_excerpt ? $post->post_excerpt : 'No description found.'), 1, 'C', 1, 1, '', '', true, 0, true, true, 0);
$pdf->setCellHeightRatio(0);
```

And here are the results which vary from first line centering for description to the more obvious title alignment even though it is from the same loop :

[image: first alignment]

[image: second alignment]

[image: third alignment]

What gives?

Makes me wonder if I should have just stuck with FPDF...

Comment: Seems like you've set the `ishtml` parameter to true. The documentation mentions that it's for *INTERNAL USE ONLY – set to true if $txt is HTML content (default = false). Never set this parameter to true, use instead writeHTMLCell() or writeHTML() methods.*. Have you tried that? In addition, you've also set the `autopadding` to true. Try to remove that.

Comment: setting it to `false` produces the same result.

Comment: Did you try the other option that was suggested? Using writeHTMLCell()?